JMeter - Utilize functions
I have the following function to generate a random MAC address:
`def macAddress() {
def rnd = new Random()
def mac = new StringBuilder()
(1..6).each {
    int value = rnd.nextInt(256)
    def hexStr = Integer.toHexString(value).padLeft(2, '0')
    mac.append(hexStr)
    if (it < 6) {
        mac.append(':')
    }
}

return mac.toString()

}`
How do I evaluate this function? Where do I view the output of this function?
What components should I use to consume this function? Please help.
Thanks for your support.
Regards,
Ajith

If you're using this code in one of the JSR223 Test Elements with Groovy language you could add the following line at the bottom:
vars.put('mac', macAddress())

Once done you should be able to access the random MAC address as ${mac} where required
In the above code vars stands for JMeterVariables class instance, see the JavaDoc for comprehensive information about all functions and fields

You can use Jsr223 Sampler to execute Java, Groovy code and For printing you can use log.info() to print in log.
